# How to deploy a MongoDB sharded cluster with SSL/TLS only on mongos instances?

Tags: mongodb, ssl, database-cluster

I have a MongoDB deployment we wanted to enable SSL for external connections, but only for external connections.

There's a number of reasons for not wanting SSL in internal communication. It adds unnecessary overhead, and we also don't want to expose the internal mongod's to the internet -- there shouldn't be any reason for them to even have an external IP. In this scenario, the mongos's should use SSL for external communication with clients and no SSL for internal communication with the mongod's.

Unfortunately in the documentation there's only discussion about four easy SSL modes:

- requireSSL : only uses SSL for all communication, including internal.
- preferSSL : uses SSL for internal communication, but allows non-SSL traffic from clients. This is pretty much the opposite of what we want.
- allowSSL : allows the use of SSL, but also allows non-SSL
- connections. disabled : No SSL whatsoever.

Neither of these helps with our situation.

In our case it's even worse, because we need SSL to migrate data from Parse.com safely, so we need to create the certificates with a commonly trusted CA (say letsencrypt) instead of our own homemade root CA.

So how do I create a MongoDB deployment that uses SSL for the external world but not internally? Do I need a reverse proxy that does SSL termination and understands the mongodb:// protocol? Or is there some other way?